# Where do the PKs come from in Bluetooth device?

Tags: public-key, diffie-hellman

I am studying the Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman (ECDH) on Bluetooth 4.2.

There are some questions about the PK..

Where do these public and private keys come from?

Who defines them?

and Will it be changed ?

if it can be changed, How to do certification ?

[image: bluetooth 4.2 authentication]

Comment: I'd suppose that the key-pairs underlying PKa and PKb get generated just before the protocol is initiated (or cached in case of really low power devices) and they get authenticated (implicitely?) at the end of "Authentication Stage 1".